# Please retag [textmessages] and [text-message] to [sms] on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The tags `text-message` (17 uses) and `textmessages` (8 uses) should be retagged to `sms` (544 uses) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed the retagging by hand, and also [proposed some tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sms/synonyms) to keep them properly sorted.